# Add title and header as List of Figures

Tags: header-footer, appendices

How can I add a new title as `UML Diagrams` to this stuff `\input{7-anhang}` in the appendix chapter?

I want to do the same as to the `List of Figures`,  first title then header. Please see my screenshot.

[image]

[image]

**text file**

```
\documentclass[
    english,
    german,
    11pt,
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    headsepline,
    footsepline
]{scrbook}
\input{commands}


    \chapter{Appendix}% 

        \listoffigures

        \listoftables

        \lstlistoflistings

        \listofalgorithms

         \clearpage     

        \fancyhead{}
        \input{7-anhang}


        %\cleardoublepage %To end \lstlistoflistings



    %using: \abk{Abk.}{Abkürzung}
        \printnomenclature
         %\bibliographystyle{acm}
        \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
        \bibliography{bibliography}

    \printindex     

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: \input{commands} makes your MWE useless.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand what you want to do. If there should be something like a list of UML Diagrams you could use the possibility of package `tocbasic` that is already loaded and used by the `scrbook` class.

```
\DeclareNewTOC[
    counterwithin=chapter,
    float,% define the floating environment uml
    nonfloat,% define the nonfloating environment uml-
    tocentrynumwidth=2.3em,% like in LOT and LOF
    tocentryindent=1.5em,% like in LOT and LOF
    listname=UML Diagrams,
    name=UML Diagram,
  ]{uml}
```

Then you can insert your UML diagrams in the floating environment `uml`. If the diagram should not float you can use the `uml-` environment or `\captionof{uml}{...}`.  To insert the list of UML Diagrams use `\listofumls`.

```
\documentclass[
    %english,
    %german,
    11pt,
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    headsepline,
    footsepline
]{scrbook}

\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\DeclareNewTOC[
    counterwithin=chapter,
    float,% define the float environment uml
    nonfloat,% define the nonfloat environment uml-
    tocentrynumwidth=2.3em,% like in LOT and LOF
    tocentryindent=1.5em,% like in LOT and LOF
    listname=UML Diagrams,
    name=UML Diagram,
  ]{uml}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Nonfloat UMLs}
\begin{uml-}
  \begin{center}
    nonfloat
  \end{center}
  \caption{Nonfloating UML}
\end{uml-}
\lipsum[1]

\foreach \i in {1,...,20}{%
  \begin{uml-}
    \begin{center}
      nonfloat
    \end{center}
    \caption{Nonfloating UML}
  \end{uml-}
  \lipsum[1]}

\chapter{Float UMLs}
\begin{uml}
  \begin{center}
    float
  \end{center}
  \caption{Floating UML}
\end{uml}
\lipsum[1]

\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{%
  \begin{uml}
    \begin{center}
      float
    \end{center}
    \caption{Floating UML}
  \end{uml}
  \lipsum[1]%
}

\chapter{Another Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  Another test
  \captionof{uml}{Another possibility}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Appendix}% 
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofumls
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

If there should be simple a chapter containing the diagrams itself you could use `\addchap{UML Diagrams}`.

```
\documentclass[
    english,
    german,
    11pt,
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    headsepline,
    footsepline
]{scrbook}

\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Appendix}% 
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

    \addchap{UML Diagrams}
    Text instead diagrams to test the headline
    \Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want regarding the appendix/chapter, but this changes that name used by `\listoffigures` (and the header).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{UML Diagrams}
\listoffigures

\newpage
header test    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tocloft` package and define your own `\listofuml` like this:

```
\newlistof{uml}{uml}{UML Diagrams}
```

This will add a new counter `uml` (the first argument) and a new command `\listofuml` to print the corresponding list. To this end, a new file with the ending `.uml` (the second argument) will be created. The title used for the new list is specified as the third argument. Then you need to add your UML diagrams to that list. You can do that, e.g., by a command like the one described in the [manual](http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf):

```
\newcommand{\uml}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{uml}
\par\noindent\textbf{UML Diagram \theuml. #1}
\addcontentsline{uml}{uml}{\protect\numberline{\theuml}#1}\par}
```

Of course, you can modify this command, e.g., to define a float for the diagram instead of just some starting text. Since you did not provide a compilable MWE or any further information on how you would like the diagrams to look like, I cannot be more specific here. The part about the header should be the same as for the list of figures that you already have.